# How can I use web-scraping to get map info text?

Tags: web, web-scraping

[image: trying to get map this info text]

I am trying to use web-scraping to get the text in the tooltip bubble on the map shown in the picture. Unfortunately I can't figure it out. Any advice would help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you post a link to the website so other can see the code?